# Who is the person deposed on Saturday and "in charge" of the foreign aid, according to Nunes?

Tags: united-states, trump-impeachment, foreign-aid

In the public hearing of Sondland today, Nunes repeatedly referred to a private deposition (apparently on Saturday) of a person whose name he did not disclose but who is apparently very important because he/she was "in charge" of the foreign aid. Nunes lamented that this person's deposition cannot be publicly discussed and that apparently he/she won't be called to publicly testify.  Who is Nunes talking about?

N.B. If you think this question is asking for speculation (3 VTCs seem to think so), consider it as: who was deposed on Saturday (the list can't be that long and the names are, I believe, public even for the private depositions, i.e. only the actual contents of deposition is private) that can reasonably said to be involved with directing US aid?

(I've managed to track down a [recording](https://youtu.be/UpsggJPmlMY) of what I saw live, in which Nunes makes that statement; the "in charge" bit is said after Nunes' minute-long digression on Watergate. Nunes summarizes his points again toward the [end of that segment](https://youtu.be/UpsggJPmlMY?t=337).)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is public knowledge, [according to CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/11/16/politics/mark-sandy-deposition-impeachment-inquiry/index.html):

> A senior career official at the Office of Management and Budget testified on Saturday about a budget process that went off the rails when nearly $400 million in US military aid to Ukraine was withheld earlier this year, and that he did not know for sure the reasoning behind the freeze in funds, sources familiar with his testimony told CNN.
>
> Mark Sandy arrived on Capitol Hill Saturday for a more than five-hour closed-door deposition in the House impeachment inquiry into President Donald Trump.
>
> He spoke about how unusual of a process it was that a political appointee came in, took over the apportionment process and placed a hold on the military aid, a source told CNN.

The Office of Management and Budget (OMB), according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_of_Management_and_Budget):

> is the largest office within the Executive Office of the President of the United States (EOP). OMB's most prominent function is to produce the President's Budget, but OMB also measures the quality of agency programs, policies, and procedures to see if they comply with the president's policies and coordinates inter-agency policy initiatives.

I note that Adam Schiff, the chairman in the impeachment hearing just now, confirms that this is the person deposed on Saturday, but that he is not the highest-ranking person in charge of foreign aid, as was claimed by Nunes in the hearing previously.

Comment: As far as I can tell (from the media) nobody else besides Sandy was deposed on Saturday, so that removes any guesswork from the answer.